# How to continuously update textView with a different delay parameter

Tags: java, android, multithreading, user-interface, view

I'm pretty new to Java and Android, and now I'm coding some application, which takes a text from ACTION.SEND and display it word by word in a TextView.

I have a method, which returns `Spanned` text, and I want to continuously update it in my TextView and implement some actions, such as pause or resume.
I've already implemented the activity using [this](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2488094) guide, but when I simply iterate over the list of words like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < listSize; ++i){
   ((TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.textView).setText(someText);
   Thread.sleep(1000 * coefficient);
}
```

the application shows only the last element of the array(when the cycle is finished). Could you advise some technique to implement this properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Problem is that you'er blocking the UI-Thread with your sleep method. Try using a Handler [(link to doc)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) and its method postDelayed [(here)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long%29).